# Как сделать распределение слов по ячейкам таблицы?

Tags: javascript

Есть многомерный массив.

```
var array = [
    [
        'один',
        'два',
        'три',
        'четыре'

        // всего 16 букв
    ]
];
```

Список слов из `array[0]` должен быть размещен в таблицу, каждая буква - это отдельная ячейка таблицы. Расположение слов в таблице - не имеет значения. Главная задача - оставить их читаемыми по одной из сторон.

```
|о|д|и|н|     |ч|е|т|ы|
|ч|е|р|т|     |т|д|о|р|
|е|т|ы|р|     |р|в|д|е|
|д|в|а|и| или |и|а|и|н|
```

Мне кажется что вставить их без разбора на буквы - нереально. Вся проблема в том, что некоторые слова могут быть "закручены" (не знаю как правильно сказать). Пример:

```
| | | | |     |ч|е|т|ы|
|ч|е|р| |     | | | |р|
|е|т|ы| |     | | | |е|
| | | | | или | | | | |
```

Разбор слов на буквы:

```
for(var value = 0; value < array[0].length; value++) { 
    for (var index = 0; index < array[0][value].length; index++) { 
        // console.log(array[0][value][index]);
    } 
}
```

Важные нюансы:

1. Общее количество букв может быть больше чем 16.
2. Ячеек по горизонтали может быть больше чем 4. По задумки их количество указывается опционально `var cells = 4;`.
3. Ячеек по вертикали может быть ровно столько - сколько требуется для
   размещения всех слов.
4. Пустых ячеек быть не должно.

Пример:

```
cells = 4     cells = 4
| | | | |     | | | | |
| | | | |     | | | | |
| | | | |     | | | | |
| | | | | или | | | | |
16 букв       | | | | |
              20 букв
```

Над этой задачей я сижу 3й день, с 10:00 до 23:00. Очень сложный для меня алгоритм. Буду рад любой помощи, любым советам относительно реализации.